# How do I store the output into a variable or into a .txt file?

Tags: python-2.7, command-line

I am running the following code in Python 2.7:

```
values = os.system("bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:"
                                  "label_image && bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image "
                                  "--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt "
                                  "--output_layer=final_result:0 --image=$HOME/Desktop/Image-3/image1.png")

print values
```

But for the values variable I am returned a 0. I believe this means that I am not getting any errors.  How do I store the output into a variable or into a .txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just redirect the output of the system call appending `> output.txt` to your command.

The output of the command will be in file `output.txt` in the directory where you invoke the command (likely the very same one you invoke your python script in).

Comment: When I append "> output.txt" to the end of the command, I get an error.

Comment: Not in the os. command - in the terminal, when you run your script. Do you run it in a terminal?

Comment: When I run the command in terminal (without the > out.txt) it runs just fine as it should.  When I add the out.txt to the end it throws an error. Is it possible that it does so because it is a bazel build command?

Comment: What OS/shell are you using? The `>` command is just a `stdout` redirection and is pretty ignorant of what you're trying to stream through it.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was saving the file to the directory; it was just throwing an error and saying it wasn't even though it was.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't readily reproduce your command, I used a simple example - try to switch to `Pyopen` in the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen

proc = Popen(['ls', '-t'], stdout = open('/path/redir.txt', 'w'))
```

Here you run the command in square brackets and redirect the output from `stdout` i.e. the terminal to a file `redir.txt`.